# ViewResult class result not work when i submit a form method post for redirect to another view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, viewresult

when i sumit a form  i want redirect to another page with viewresult class. 
this is my filter code :

```
 [ValidateSpamFilter(duration: 60, isAddress: false, keepRequestinCache: true)]
    // HttpPost Method For Submit Form . you can add comment by this method .
    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddComment(CommentAddDTO Comments)
```

and

```
 filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "~/Error/Index"  };
```

this just work for actionresutland partialviewresult **GET** methods. 
But i want uses for **actionresutland** Post Method . Because i submit a form method and i get below Error

> '~/Error/Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:\r\n~/Error/Index"